# Separar figuras - Python - Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Estoy haciendo un pequeño programa de prueba que grafica varias figuras y actualiza los datos mediante un botón. Pero no encontré forma de separar las figuras para que no se solapen los valores de la barra de colores con los del eje "y" del próximo cuadro. Alguna idea? Probé con la opción figura.subplots_adjusts(wspace = cantidad a separar) que agrega espacio a los costados de cada figura, pero la barra de colores al estar en un eje independiente también me la separa demasiado de su cuadro original. Alguna idea?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

root = tk.Tk()

# Variables
matriz_datos = None
figura = None
ejes = None
canvas = None

def crear_graficos():
    global matriz_datos, figura, ejes, canvas
    for i in ejes:
        for j in i:
            j.clear()
    for j in range(0, 2):
        for i in range(0, 6, 2):
            matriz_datos = np.ndarray((5, 5), dtype = np.int, buffer = np.random.randint(100, size = (5, 5)))
            sns.heatmap(matriz_datos, ax = ejes[j, i], cbar_ax = ejes[j, i + 1])
    figura.canvas.draw()

def actualizar_datos():
    crear_graficos()

figura, ejes = plt.subplots(2, 6, figsize = (15, 10), dpi = 80, gridspec_kw = {"width_ratios": [10, 1, 10, 1, 10, 1]})
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figura, root)
#figura.subplots_adjust(wspace = 0.5)
canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x = 10, y = 10)
crear_graficos()

boton = tk.Button(root, text = "Actualizar", command = actualizar_datos)
boton.place(x = 10, y = 750)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo pude solucionar con

```
constrained_layout = True
```

Comment: Hola Caeta, me alegra que encontraras la solución a tu problema y que la compartieras con los demás usuarios. Pero te comento, esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido, deberías editarla para añadir algo más de detalle: ¿qué hace `constrained_layout = True`? ¿Dónde se pondría: es parte del código o de la configuración? Lee [answer] para más información y recomendaciones para mejorar tus respuestas. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Para separar subplots se puede utilizar `plt.tight_layout`.

Agregue esta línea en esta sección del código y separa los gráficos como se espera:

```
figura, ejes = plt.subplots(2, 6, figsize = (15, 10), dpi = 80, gridspec_kw = {"width_ratios": [10, 1, 10, 1, 10, 1]})
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figura, root)
#figura.subplots_adjust(wspace = 0.5)
plt.tight_layout()
canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x = 10, y = 10)
crear_graficos()

boton = tk.Button(root, text = "Actualizar", command = actualizar_datos)
boton.place(x = 10, y = 750)
```